# here-api matrix route summary is different than the one you get when calling getroute with the same routeId - why is that?

Tags: here-api

I'm calling the matrix routing API:

https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=my_app_id&app_code=my_app_code&start0=41.63146,-87.619662&destination0=41.905806,-87.630023&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&matrixAttributes=summary&summaryAttributes=traveltime,distance,routeId&departure=2018-08-13T06:47:30-05:00

and getting a distance of 41698, and the routeId if I want to see further details on this route:

```
{"summary":{"distance":41698,"travelTime":2471,"costFactor":2511,"routeId":"AIEACAAAAB4AAABaAAAAmgAAAJ8AAAB42mOYz8DAxMQABKeCNzquODYrlgEKcibcFHVjFLJh+P8fIvBhPwMS4ALiyy4nXJgY3hWsd5TecQauMfvCHdHzvHg1XmB8spIRaDFccMeSjE9TQQxFB6YGhhRGCUd/JgMQv4EJADjbIRoCEs8U"}}
```

I then call get getroute with the routeId I got:

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getroute.json?app_id=my_app_id&app_code=my_app_code&routeId=AIEACAAAAB4AAABaAAAAmgAAAJ8AAAB42mOYz8DAxMQABKeCNzquODYrlgEKcibcFHVjFLJh+P8fIvBhPwMS4ALiyy4nXJgY3hWsd5TecQauMfvCHdHzvHg1XmB8spIRaDFccMeSjE9TQQxFB6YGhhRGCUd/JgMQv4EJADjbIRoCEs8U

and now I get a distance of 38650:

```
"summary":{"distance":38650,"trafficTime":5066,"baseTime":2401,"flags":["tunnel","motorway","builtUpArea"],"text":"The trip takes <span class=\"length\">38.7 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">40 mins</span>.","travelTime":2401,"_type":"RouteSummaryType"}}
```

is this the expected behaviour? why?

Answer (score 1):

MxN Matrix Routing and 1xN Routing are not using same algorithm thus you won’t get exact same result.
Matrix Routing is doing some local “simplification” to go faster in computing the whole matrix.